# Internet Explorer blocks xbap with ClickOnce

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, clickonce, xbap

I created today my first `xbap` application, and deployed with `ClickOnce`, .NET 4.5.
Microsoft did a great job with documenting everything except the small thing of - how does it actually needs to be deployed?? I mean for real...

- I started an IIS service.
- Configured in my project publish settings the URL location.
- In 'Security' tab i checked the 'Enable ClickOnce security settings', and chose 'full-trust application' since I'm using local PC resources.
- In 'Signing' I created a 'Test Certificate' and installed it to the relevant 'Trusted' folders.

It almost works, but IE blocks it, saying the application type is disabled.
I googled the problem and found the simple solution that all web sites offer - just change the security configuration in IE, enable this `XAML` settings in your security zone - and that's it!
Fantastic, it works perfect in my development environment.
But if my app is "signed", why is it being blocked?
Or at least, how can i verify that this is a signing issue?
It seems that IE default security for 'internet' zone just blocks `WPF` apps regardless of the signing state. But in that case, why `xbap` even exists? I did say today: "OMGGG I can't believe this actually worksss!!!", but few hours later I realized I found a huge rock made of gold but I can't pick it up to my truck so yeah it's shiny but what am I suppose to do with that?

Anyways, I'd be glad to finally found a solution for deploying `xbap` apps without asking the user to change its IE security settings.
otherwise, given the requirements:

- Use native DLLs (that's why i didn't use `Silverlight`).
- Application that runs from a browser (or from IE).
- **Without** using PC local resources. (maybe i could make the `xbap` work on partial trust mode).

Does it change anything?
Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

> ...a solution for deploying xbap apps without asking the user to change
>   its IE security settings.

It looks to me that the users will always need to set or change the "XAML browser applications" in IE to 'Enable' or 'Prompt' to have any XBAPs run.  And on IE they are disabled by default.