# Unable to load entityframework in XBAP solution from internet. Works on LAN

Tags: clickonce, entity-framework-6, publishing, xbap

XBAP: Unable to load assembly EntityFramework when accessing from internet.  Works from LAN

I found these posts (and many more) but it did not help:

- Deploying XBAP with win32 DLL 
  [Deploying XBAP with win32 DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758568/deploying-xbap-with-win32-dll)
- Internet Explorer blocks xbap with
  ClickOnce    [Internet Explorer blocks xbap with ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103595/internet-explorer-blocks-xbap-with-clickonce)

I have an XBAP solution that I have been developing in vs2012.  The solution comprises of the following projects:

- XBAP main project (main project)
- WCF service (used for user authentication)
- Data Access Layer project to get data from sql/entity framework

XBAP is published in full trust.  I created a test cert and installed it on the client machine to enable full trust.   The website is on the client machine trusted sites zone.
The solution has 1 SQL Express database.  I have written everything in c#.  I wrote this project as Database-first.

I am using EF 6.1.1.  Yes, the error shows that it is trying to find EF 6.0.0.0 but I think this is okay (??).  Can you confirm?  I used NuGet and uninstalled EF, reinstalled EF, cleaned the solution, rebuid and publish.  I was hoping that this would resolve referencing issues in the app and web.config files.   It still keeps the EF6.0.0.0 reference in the .config files and I get the assembly error.

In the properties for the EF .dll, I set copy=true.   So, it should be copying entityframework.dll to the bin folder.   What I am seeing though are a bunch of xxxx.dll.deploy files.   This is okay, I believe, to conform to the OS mime types.   When the user accesses the site, the app will download and automatically convert .dll.deploy to .dll.

I signed my solution with a test certificate which I loaded into the client ie11 browser(s).

I have 3 environments:

- development platform (laptop with vs debug),
- win 2003 staging server (eventually this will be 2012 too),
- win 2012 production server.

The way that the project works is as follows:

1. User enters url for the site:
   http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyyyyy.xbap
2. The user is presented with a login page.
3. User enters credentials.  The WCF project validates credentials
   against the DB.
4. User is now presented with a main screen with menus
5. If user clicks on any menu that dips into the database, I get an
   error "Unable to load assembly entityframework" (more details
   below).

The solution works in the debug environment.   No errors.
The solution also works in the staging and production environment when I access the xbap application from the LAN.
When I try to access the staging or production environment from the internet, I get the following error:

----------------------------ERROR MESSAGE IN IE -------------------------------------

```
Startup URI: http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyyyyy.xbap
Application Identity: http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyyyyy.xbap#yyyyyyyyy.xbap, Version=1.0.0.118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ssssssssssssssssss, 
processorArchitecture=msil/yyyyyyyyy.exe, Version=1.0.0.118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ssssssssssssssssss, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, 
Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, 
IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, 
IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)
   at System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.StartDispatcherInBrowser(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
-----------------------
PresentationHost.exe v4.0.31106.0 built by: Main - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PresentationHost.exe
ntdll.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
kernel32.dll v6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432) - C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
KERNELBASE.dll v6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432) - C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
SYSFER.DLL v12.1.4013.4013 - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SYSFER.DLL
ADVAPI32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
msvcrt.dll v7.0.7601.17744 (win7sp1_gdr.111215-1535) - C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
sechost.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
RPCRT4.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
SspiCli.dll v6.1.7601.18496 (win7sp1_gdr.140605-0343) - C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
CRYPTBASE.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
USER32.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
GDI32.dll v6.1.7601.18275 (win7sp1_gdr.131002-1533) - C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
LPK.dll v6.1.7601.18177 (win7sp1_gdr.130605-1534) - C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
USP10.dll v1.0626.7601.18454 (win7sp1_gdr.140424-1533) - C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
ole32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
OLEAUT32.dll v6.1.7601.17676 - C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
mscoree.dll v4.0.40305.0 (Main.040305-0000) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll
SHLWAPI.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
WININET.dll v11.00.9600.16428 (winblue_gdr.131013-1700) - C:\Windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
version.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.DLL
api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
normaliz.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\normaliz.DLL
iertutil.dll v11.00.9600.17207 (winblue_gdr_escrow.140618-1157) - C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
USERENV.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\USERENV.dll
profapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\profapi.dll
urlmon.dll v11.00.9600.17207 (winblue_gdr_escrow.140618-1157) - C:\Windows\syswow64\urlmon.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-ole32-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-ole32-l1-1-0.dll
SHELL32.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
IMM32.DLL v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
MSCTF.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
PresentationHost_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationHost_v0400.dll
MSVCR110_CLR0400.dll v11.00.50938.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCR110_CLR0400.dll
PSAPI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
CLBCatQ.DLL v2001.12.8530.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
CRYPTSP.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CRYPTSP.dll
rsaenh.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
RpcRtRemote.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll
ieproxy.dll v11.00.9600.17207 (winblue_gdr_escrow.140618-1157) - C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l2-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l2-1-0.dll
Secur32.dll v6.1.7601.18496 (win7sp1_gdr.140605-0343) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Secur32.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l2-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l2-1-0.dll
WS2_32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
NSI.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
mswsock.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
wship6.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
IPHLPAPI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL
WINNSI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WINNSI.DLL
DNSAPI.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DNSAPI.dll
dhcpcsvc6.DLL v6.1.7601.17970 (win7sp1_gdr.121009-0412) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
dhcpcsvc.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.DLL
wshtcpip.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
netprofm.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\netprofm.dll
nlaapi.dll v6.1.7601.17761 (win7sp1_gdr.120112-1636) - C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll
rasadhlp.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll
fwpuclnt.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
npmproxy.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\npmproxy.dll
Comctl32.dll v6.10 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\Comctl32.dll
dfshim.dll v4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dfshim.dll
mscoreei.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
clr.dll v4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
msxml3.dll v8.110.7601.18431 - C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll
SXS.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SXS.DLL
PresentationHostProxy.dll v4.0.40305.0 built by: Main - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PresentationHostProxy.dll
mshtml.dll v11.00.9600.17207 (winblue_gdr_escrow.140618-1157) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.dll
UxTheme.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UxTheme.dll
msimtf.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msimtf.dll
msls31.dll v3.10.349.0 - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msls31.dll
d2d1.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d2d1.dll
DWrite.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll
dxgi.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll
dwmapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll
WINTRUST.dll v6.1.7601.18205 (win7sp1_gdr.130708-1532) - C:\Windows\syswow64\WINTRUST.dll
CRYPT32.dll v6.1.7601.18277 (win7sp1_gdr.131005-0934) - C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
MSASN1.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
d3d11.dll v6.2.9200.16570 (win8_gdr.130327-1526) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll
IEFRAME.dll v11.00.9600.17207 (winblue_gdr_escrow.140618-1157) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IEFRAME.dll
api-ms-win-downlevel-shell32-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shell32-l1-1-0.dll
uiautomationcore.dll v7.0.0.0 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uiautomationcore.dll
OLEACC.dll v7.0.0.0 (win7sp1_gdr.110826-1504) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OLEACC.dll
jscript9.dll v11.00.9600.17207 (winblue_gdr_escrow.140618-1157) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\jscript9.dll
windowscodecs.dll v6.2.9200.16809 (win8_gdr.140127-1505) - C:\Windows\system32\windowscodecs.dll
mlang.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
mscorlib.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\ce5f61c5754789df97be8dc991c47d07\mscorlib.ni.dll
nlssorting.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
System.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\ff26cc03e6d57d8abd13b990332e67c6\System.ni.dll
WindowsBase.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\acf97bfe2a931d4a47253b26b7218991\WindowsBase.ni.dll
PresentationCore.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore
\a74542efbeb46445949a39026c501132\PresentationCore.ni.dll
PresentationFramework.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatio5ae0f00f#\a4b45c44490c75bc2fb22780e7ef087d
\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
wpfgfx_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
PresentationNative_v0400.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll
System.Xaml.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\3fe705796c6a41d4889d9001d1c56af8\System.Xaml.ni.dll
clrjit.dll v4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
System.Xml.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\bada32953bb6b16a53d653eae23d78dc\System.Xml.ni.dll
PresentationFramework.classic.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatiod51afaa5#
\edec2d7b3ecaabfc5c72d7615d884f79\PresentationFramework.classic.ni.dll
d3d9.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll
d3d8thk.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d8thk.dll
System.Configuration.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\bbc48ec4245e502ae19b0601d3799c9e
\System.Configuration.ni.dll
WtsApi32.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WtsApi32.dll
WINSTA.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WINSTA.dll
PresentationFramework-SystemXml.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatio49d6fefe#
\47e7fc401facd4a5d3f2237f16948f36\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.ni.dll
msctfui.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msctfui.dll
UIAutomationTypes.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\UIAutomationTypes
\75b6a68103e1b76063d9f69b8275ae61\UIAutomationTypes.ni.dll
WINMM.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WINMM.dll
System.Core.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\dce99d8de14d8a015313db98c72552ee\System.Core.ni.dll
System.ServiceModel.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.ServiceModel
\24bf0c88c0465485f4b842df043b3f45\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
SMDiagnostics.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\SMDiagnostics
\78652b7fa68ee058bff6a118c657f565\SMDiagnostics.ni.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runteb92aa12#
\f6d7bb59f318c130d68816a89335d05e\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll
System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Servd1dec626#
\34b53ecafa1d7ccc7ca961d722b5d983\System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll
System.Transactions.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Transactions
\2053b0e14f1e64a5c5d6d1c4d01485a2\System.Transactions.ni.dll
System.Transactions.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
System.IdentityModel.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.IdentityModel\1e5e19d119e04b93da3d45153abd60fd
\System.IdentityModel.ni.dll
rasapi32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasapi32.dll
rasman.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasman.dll
rtutils.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rtutils.dll
winhttp.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winhttp.dll
webio.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\webio.dll
credssp.dll v6.1.7601.18489 (win7sp1_gdr.140529-2100) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\credssp.dll
CFGMGR32.dll v6.1.7601.17621 (win7sp1_gdr.110523-2108) - C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
System.Net.Http.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Net.Http
\d7a1bbd56dc15a29c2450b177f9468d7\System.Net.Http.ni.dll
System.Data.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data\6bbed231aec6fd82547e09474da0b2f9\System.Data.ni.dll
System.Data.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
MMDevAPI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MMDevAPI.DLL
PROPSYS.dll v7.00.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PROPSYS.dll
actxprxy.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\actxprxy.dll
UIAutomationProvider.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\UIAutomationProvider
\c94c36c9ae776de930f2aacb6dd51c38\UIAutomationProvider.ni.dll
System.Numerics.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Numerics
\4c8a153aa66fcd62db6fff269a2ef2b4\System.Numerics.ni.dll
System.Data.OracleClient.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data86569bbf#
\42e4e0c2624e0f686d87fa4011455fac\System.Data.OracleClient.ni.dll
System.Data.OracleClient.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll
WindowsFormsIntegration.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsForm0b574481#
\1ab52f8951c2ab97592ec25830dd5165\WindowsFormsIntegration.ni.dll
System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml.Linq
\b6c7a1ca929c1b10f36b683c9f1a0517\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll
System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#
\ee550c3d485d44c7fbeeafe12a3e318b\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll
System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#
\ee550c3d485d44c7fbeeafe12a3e318b\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll v4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
security.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\security.dll
schannel.dll v6.1.7601.18489 (win7sp1_gdr.140529-2100) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\schannel.dll
diasymreader.dll v11.0.50938.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
```

*

Thanks for your help on this.  If you need any more info, please let me know.   I am hoping that someone else has seen this problem in clickonce deployments or xbap

development.

Comment: [Clickonce over internet only runs on internet zone trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw.aspx). For Entity Framework to run, you need ADO.Net. ADO.Net does not run under internet zone trust.

Comment: Thank you, Aron.  I created a test cert and installed it in the client Internet Explorer under the Trusted Publishers and under the Trusted Root.  I also have the site in the Trusted Sites in IE/Tools/Internet Options/Security.   Are you saying that is not enough?  Can you please also elaborate on what you mean by "you need ADO.Net?"  What do I need to do to add it to my project(s).  Thanks

Comment: If memory serves, XBAPs run in a sandbox within IE, and has access to a restricted set of the .net framework. One of the components that you cannot use is ADO.Net, which is a prerequisite of Entity Framework. This makes sense, because ADO.Net lives in the .net Serverside Extensions, and XBAPs are for client side applications. This enforces the best practice of requiring you to write a server for data access.

Comment: @Aron I have successfully run my own xbap in-browser locally, but I am getting this same error now on a client. I _doubt_ it is the sandboxing that does it, since even locally it would run in the same sandbox. Trust issues I had as well, but indeed, like mtdscomm, I solved those with a certificate.

Comment: It could be that you don't have EF in the XBAP manifest. Also check that your target machine does have the full .net framework installed as opposed to just the "Client Profile".

Comment: The client machine has the following framework installed: "Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.1".  I believe this is the full version.   I have .xbap in the manifest and it looks good.  One change I did make to the manifest a few days ago was to change the mime for .manifest.  I had it as application/x-ms-manifest.  Several sites suggested changing it to application/manifest.

Comment: oerkelens:   You said that you solved it with a certificate.  I am using a test certificate.   Is a test cert enough or might this be the reason?

Comment: I'm using a test cert as well, only thing it solved was the trust issues. But in the current situation, nothing is mentioned about trust, of forbidden access... so I assume the trust issues as such are gone. Now Just EF 6 cannot be found...

Comment: oerkelens - you are having the same issue as me.  I get the dreaded "Unable to find assembly" entity framework message on the client side.

Comment: I know - that is how I ended up here :) I hope you get an answer!

Comment: @Aron, I think you may be right with your input where you said "One of the components that you cannot use is ADO.Net, which is a prerequisite of Entity Framework. This makes sense, because ADO.Net lives in the .net Serverside Extensions, and XBAPs are for client".  I found the following today: "The security sandbox does not support direct database connectivity."  If this is true, I need to do one of two things: 1) convert my XBAP to Silverlight or WPF client, or 2) run all data access routines through the WCF project.  I wish XBAP had shown this problem in debug.  Talk about a hidden trap.

Comment: Silverlight is even more cut down than xbap

Comment: Understood, but Silverlight runs on the server side so I should be able to access the database right from the Silverlight project (I hope).  I have not programmed in Silverlight, but hopefully this will allow me to do a lot of cutting & pasting from XBAP pages to Silverlight without having to do a lot of redesign.  What do you all think ---  what is the best approach - Silverlight conversion, or a WPF windows app connected to remote database?

Comment: I thought Silverlight ran server side, but it does not seem to.   So as Aron pointed out, I will not gain much by converting XBAP to Silverlight.  Lots to think about and research.  WCF data access may be the way to go.

Comment: I found "I found the following today: "The security sandbox does not support direct database connectivity." too, but on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAML_Browser_Applications) it adds: (unless the application is fully trusted). I set up my application as xbap and clickonce to use two different db's with the same data layer, so I am not (yet) willing to overhaul that and implement two data access layers for the same functionality...

Comment: I found something that may fix this.   Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172240.aspx    Here is the excerpt that is interesting - "...By default, ClickOnce applications signed with self-certs and deployed over the internet cannot utilize Trusted Application Deployment."  I think this is why we are having problems, oerkelens.   I think that if we sign and deploy our xbaps with a cert from a vendor, then it will work.

Comment: Here is another link that gives info about Trusted Application Deployment Overview:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01daf08f.aspx

Comment: If you plan on buying a cert, make sure you buy a code-signing one.   I installed a VeriSign free trial cert only to find out it only works for https web hosting.  When I have results from my cert code-signing and xbap access to database, I will post back results.

Comment: Guys, I purchased a code-signing cert and installed the .cer on the client machine in the Trusted Root Cert Authorities and in the Trusted Publishers.  I also signed and published the code with the .pfx key.  Still no luck.  Same error. Anyone have any ideas?   How do I verify that the app is running full trust?  I did a mageUI on the .manifest file and it did show unrestricted=true.

Comment: I found out that the xbap runs just fine on my own PC (in a different domain!) when approaching the webserver. Both my PC and the VM run windows 7 and they _should_ be identically configured. I'm now hunting for the difference between the two that makes the xbap fail. It does _not_ seem to be a certificate problem.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing your findings.

Comment: I found this post on SO.   The person is asking how to connect XBAP to a database.   There was no documented answer on the post.   I cannot comment on the post to ask if they found a solution because I dont' have enough reputation points.   Can someone please ask?  Thanks:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602023/how-to-access-a-database-from-xbap-securely

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but after having put aside the problem for a while, I discovered a way to solve the error (at least in my case).

The big issue is that **the error message has nothing to do with the actual error**.

Since the error message sent me off chasing ghosts in all the wrong places, it took me way to long to see the obvious: **I was using the wrong connection string**.

Yes, stupid beginners mistake, but during development, my xbap referenced *localhost* - which worked fine as my development DB resided on my own machine. The deployed version also worked fine on the server - again, because there was a SQL server instance there.

However, when any client tried to run the xbap, it runs, of course, locally, and it can simply not find the database.

In a nice world, that would lead to an error message saying "cannot find database" or "cannot connect to database", right? The world isn't that nice.

Running my xbap locally (where it ran without trouble) with a changed, dummy, connection string gave enabled me to reproduce the error.

So, the answer seems to be: **check and double check your connection strings**.

As for some of the points mentioned in the comments about EF not possibly working with WPF - it does work. It works just fine.

Comment: Big thanks for this.  I was triple checking dependency references before I came across this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the domain user account under whose credentials the IE had been started didn't have appropriate rights on the DB...